# Date column is not displayed in sql

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, teradata

I am using Oracle express for the database comparisons (Teradata and Adaptive Server IQ)
When i am trying to connect a database and try to display all the columns using select function, all the columns except date columns are getting displayed.
can i know a solution for this?

Comment: Can you provide code and samples of what is and isn't being returned?

Comment: For eg: columns like calendar begin date and end date are not being returned

Comment: @RRR Please post the query that you are using. If possible, please post the table definition as well.

Comment: Just a direct move. The only difference is i ma connecting the database via oracle express. For eg: select calbegindate,calenddate from table@database